# How to find the highest value in a Dictionary, as well as all the keys that map to it?

Tags: c#

For example,

This is my dictionary, mydict

key value
1   1500
2   1900
3   1760
4   1800
5   1460

It should return the maximum value (1900), and the key (2)

But for this:

key value
1   1500
2   1900
3   1760
4   1900
5   1460

It should return maximum value 1900, and the keys (2, 4)

How should I be doing this? Is System.Linq helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the stack overflow!!

Here is an example as per your question:

```
            Dictionary<int, int> keyValuePairs = new Dictionary<int, int>();
            keyValuePairs.Add(1, 1500);
            keyValuePairs.Add(2, 1900);
            keyValuePairs.Add(3, 1760);
            keyValuePairs.Add(4, 1900);
            keyValuePairs.Add(5, 1460);

            int maxValue=keyValuePairs.Values.Max();
            var maxResult = keyValuePairs.Where(x => x.Value == maxValue).Select(x => new { x.Key, x.Value }).ToList();
            foreach (var item in maxResult)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Key: {0}  Value: {1}", item.Key, item.Value);
            }
```

**Output**

[image: output]

Comment: Oneliners not always a good code. `keyValuePairs.Values.Max()` will be calculated for every pair in the dictionary, move it to variable.

Comment: It will execute only once.